# could'nt read correct values of vector produced from file

Tags: c++, vector, atof, root-framework

I am trying to read text file line by line and then read each column as vector but when i am tryin to cout first column it shows zeros i.e. not reading the file correctly.

```
int main(void)
{


    ifstream myfile ("data1.txt");
    string line;


    if (myfile.is_open())
   {

        int ln=1;

     while ( getline (myfile,line) )
     {      
      if(ln==1){ln++; continue;}
        istringstream iss(line);
        string word;
        vector<double> column;
        int w=1;
        while(iss >> word) 
        {   

            //double dw=atof(Form("%s",word));      
            column.push_back(atof(Form("%s",word)));
            cout<<column[0];

        w++;


        }

    ln++;
    cout<<"\n";
    }
   myfile.close();
  }
  //else
  else cout<<"Unable to open file"; 
  cout<<"\n";
  return ;
  }enter code here
```

Comment: Have you debugged it? Does `word` contain correct values? What is `Form`? - does it return correct value?

Comment: yes "marcinj" when i ran cout<<word; without defining vector it gave me same values as that in my text file. But with vector it does'nt.

Answer (score 0):

`push_back` appends an element as last element of the vector while `columns[0]` always refers to the first element of the vector.

Is the first element `0`

Is there another problem?

(Please explain what is `Form`, give an example of input file and output in the command line)

Comment: yes first column's first element is zero.
yes there is another problem i want to use these vectors in plotting graphs using root framework.
Form is used to read word as string and also because atof takes 1 parameter to convert string into double. i only want my text to be stored as double in the vector.

Comment: But why not use  `word.c_str()` which is the standard way to convert a `string` to a `char[]` suitable for `atof`?

Comment: I would say string stream is a more standard way.. c_str does not return char */char[] it returns const char */const char [].

Comment: Where is the problem if you pass it to `atof`?

Comment: when using atof it is giving me zero as value

Comment: @styko It tempts you to use ftoa and itoa.

Answer (score 0):

First of all learn how to indent and consistently use some scheme for inserting blank lines that makes  sense. When you do that you can read your own code and figure out if it is doing what you think it is.

Second. Save Form("%s",word) in a string ( for now call it form_string) add this  line `cout<<"form returns "<<form_string<<endl;` 99.99% probably it will print zeros.

Finally change:  `cout<<column[0];` to  `cout<<column[0]<<" ";` or `cout<<*(column.rbegin())<<" ";`. The latter prints out all the values that you read, the former prints out the first value you read over and over.